# range.find method does not return nothing when no matching format part

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

The function below aims getting as text, the firt bold part of a pharagraph of a word document. Pharagraphs are passed as ranges to the function.

```
Private Function GetFirstBoldPartofAPharagraph(rngPharagraph) As String
    With rngPharagraph.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Execute Format:=True
    End With

   rngPharagraph.Select

   GetFirstBoldPartofAPharagraph = rngPharagraph.Text

   Set rng = Nothing
End Function
```

Here `rngPharagraph` comes from `myRange` (`lngPar` is the number of the pharagraphs of a word document)

```
Set myRange = objDoc.Paragraphs(lngPar).Range
```

This code is to be executed in an excel worksheet. The problem is that, if there is a bold part, it finds and `rngPharagraph.Text` gets that part; but if there is no bold part `rngPharagraph.text` returns all pharagraph instead of returning `nothing`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check for the `Find` object result with its `Found` property:

```
Private Function GetFirstBoldPartofAPharagraph(rngPharagraph As Range) As String
    With rngPharagraph.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Execute Format:=True
    End With

    If rngPharagraph.Find.Found Then
        rngPharagraph.Select
        GetFirstBoldPartofAPharagraph = rngPharagraph.Text
    End If
End Function
```